# Get the right window for NSDocument's readFromData:::

Tags: objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, nsdocument

I've successfully implemented a NSDocument class in my Cocoa App which is also able to save data properly. But I have problems when it's about opening files.

This is my basic setup:

**NSDocument** MyFile ==xib File=> MyFile.xib

**NSObject** FileClass as processing class

FileClass is a class that compresses/decompresses files and is connected to the window's textfield in MyFile.xib. Saving is done via the default NSNotificationCenter. The data needs to be processed in this class because it does not contain raw NSStrings.

Let's  say I have three documents that need to opened I have three NSDocument instances that now send their data via the NSNotificationsCenter. Because I have three NSDocuments I have three windows and three FileClass instances. Now it's just luck if the correct FileClass receives the data because I have no possibility to filter whether the received data is proposed for this window. A random FileClass now processes the file and sets the text of its associated Text View. So Window 1 could show the data that were thought to be shown in Window 3.

The data flow:

NSDocument => readFromData => NSNotificationCenter => random FileClass => associated TextView.

To narrow it down: How do I route the data to its correct window and how/where do I include FileClass in this construct?

Thanks in advance!

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an indication for a major design flaw if you have to force your document data through the notification center to your viewing classes. Why do you have to do that? What issues are you trying to circumvent?

Comment: Seems like you're right. I could implement my custom classes in the NSDocument class. But how do I access my text field then? I can't bind the text view to the NSDocument class in the Interface Builder, or am I wrong?

Comment: Of course you can! NSDocument belongs into the group of the controller classes, which means that its purpose is to take information from model classes (the data you read), interpreting them and sending them to the view classes (text view, custom views, etc.) for user interaction. The instance of NSDocument that is loading the XIB file from Interface Builder is actually set as taht XIBs "File's Owner". So in IB, the "File's Owner" box is actually your instance of NSDocument.

Comment: Keep in mind though that the NSDocument is initialized and reads data from the disk long before the XIB and all your interface stuff is loaded. This means that you really need a few model classes to store whatever you read from disk, or at least keep that data around in some instance variable of NSDocument, so that you are able to fill your views with data at a later stage.